# Binding Enum to ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, enums

I need to bind an `Enum` to WPF `ComboBox`, I followed **EXACTLY** the steps in the great post [here](https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/) (The Better Way) but I always gets this error:

```
Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 'local:AppLanguage'
```

Sample project that contain the error [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nsr6ql1yhk70pjd/DataBindEnumsSample.zip?dl=0)

Thanks in advances

Comment: Can't you just `[ComboBox].ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Applanguage));`?

Comment: Please take a look https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/

Comment: That's not exactly necessary :) I mean, do you need bindings here? It looks like a simple selector. So, adding the enum type directly to the Items is pretty straightforward. If you need the extra description, the converter is enough. If you want to add that `EnumBindingSourceExtension`, make sure it's reachable. Make a class for it, using the same name, the same for the enum. Then what you found in that example will work out-of-the-box, just adding `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:EnumBindingSource {x:Type local:Applanguage}}}"` to the markup.

Comment: With *Make a class for it*, I mean add a class file to the Project and paste/overwrite its default name with your `EnumBindingSourceExtension` class object. You can handle nested classes in the markup, eventually, but you really don't have to.

Comment: The `Binding` is redundant. Just use the extension directly. It's not possible to help without _any_ details. Please post the XAML and the definition of the enum and the extension. Then I'm able to help you. Don't expect people to follow your link to download your project and run it on their machines. Always post a minimal viable example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to the question... eventually your external link will die and this will be hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The enum type is a) nested and b) has a lowercase 'l', so is actually called `MainWindow.Applanguage`.

In order to write this in XAML you have to use a plus character for the nested delimiter, like this:

```
{x:Type local:MainWindow+Applanguage}
```

Comment: Then you have changed something else in the solution since you uploaded it, not inserted the code above into the XAML file correctly, or not built your changes.